# Apply a function against corresponding elements of a List

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have two List each of which contains a sequence of Tuples. I'm trying to
run a function against coresponding elements of the List.

```
  val l1 = List(("a" , Seq( ("link1", 2) , ("link2" , 4) )))
                                                  //> l1  : List[(String, Seq[(String, Int)])] = List((a,List((link1,2), (link2,3)
                                                  //| )))
  val l2 = List(("b" , Seq( ("link1", 2) , ("link3" , 3) , ("link2" , 3) )))
                                                  //> l2  : List[(String, Seq[(String, Int)])] = List((b,List((link1,2), (link3,3)
                                                  //| , (link2,3))))
```

So I'm trying to group two lists to below format and then apply function against the corresponding elements :

```
  l1Grouped = Seq( ("link1", 2) , ("link2" , 4)
  l2Grouped = Seq( ("link1", 2) , ("link2" , 3)
```

Once the elements are in above format I can use `zip` to apply the function.

"link3" is not contained in either List since it is just contained in l2

To achieve this I'm trying intersect function below to group the items :

```
 l1(0)._2.intersect(l2(0)._2)                    //> res0: Seq[(String, Int)] = List((link1,2), (link2,3))
```

But this adds the similar items once.

How can I function be run against corresponding elements of vars l1 & l2 defined above ?

In practice l1 & 2 are of type spark obj RDD , I'm using a List in this example for testing but same solution should be compatible with an RDD.

Comment: Are `l1` and `l2` both of length 1? If not then how do you transform them from `l1` to `l1Grouped`?

Comment: @ggovan in above example for simplicity they are of length 1. In reality they will be of length > 1 . "how do you transform them from l1 to l1Grouped" thats what I don't know. l1Grouped & l2Grouped are they transformations I'm trying to create

Comment: How do you want them to match up? By "link_X_"? Or by equality of the full tuple? As it is `l1Grouped == l2Grouped`.

Comment: @ggovan apologies for ambiguity, I should have used more accurate test data. I want them to match based on "link_X_"

Comment: @ggovan ive updated question to be more accurate

Comment: wingedsubmariner's answer is spot on then.  `yield (k,v1,v2)` will give you a `Seq[(String,Int,Int)]` where the first Int is from l1 the second from l2. It's a really smart way of doing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither `intersect` or `zip` is needed:

```
val map = l1(0)._2.toMap
for {
  (k, v1) <- l2(0)._2
  v2 <- map.get(k)
} yield ... // Return a value based on v1 and v2
```

We store the elements from list one into a map, then interate over list two, only returning values if they also exist in the map.